# Python - Add tuple values to repeated keys in a dict

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, key, tuples

I've been trying to convert this test.csv file:

```
a,b,4
a,c,2
b,a,4
b,c,1
b,d,5
c,a,2
c,b,1
c,d,8
c,e,10
d,b,5
d,c,8
d,e,2
d,z,6
e,c,10
e,d,2
e,z,3
z,d,6
z,e,3
```

Into this formatting. So far when I try to convert it, the repeated keys get override and not added as a second value. Could someone show me how to get this formatting?

```
G1 = {
    'a': [('b', 4), ('c', 2)],
    'b': [('a', 4), ('c', 1), ('d', 5)],
    'c': [('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('d', 8), ('e', 10)],
    'd': [('b', 5), ('c', 8), ('e', 2), ('z', 6)],
    'e': [('c', 10), ('d', 2), ('z', 3)],
    'z': [('d', 6), ('e', 3)],
}
```

This is the code that converts the file into a dict, but replaces the new values for the repeated keys. I'd like to know how to add the values as tuples and for repeated keys, add the tuples as second values.

```
reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv'))
arcos = {}
for row in reader:
    key = row[0]
    arcos[key] = row[1:]
```

And the result:

```
{
'a': ['c', 2.0],
 'b': ['d', 5.0],
 'c': ['e', 10.0],
 'd': ['z', 6.0],
 'e': ['z', 3.0],
 'z': ['e', 3.0]
}
```

I hope what I've requested is possible.

Comment: perhaps you didnt use ``append`` for List type.
please show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `defaultdict` with the `list` class, iterate the file and append the tuples:

```
from collections import defaultdict

G = defaultdict(list)

with open('test.csv') as file:
    for line in file:
        key, letter, digit = line.strip().split(',')
        digit = int(digit)
        G[key].append((letter, digit))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` method and make this easy:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('out.csv') as f:
    print({k:[(i.split(',')[1],i.split(',')[2]) for i in g] for k, g in groupby([i.strip() for i in f],lambda x: x.split(',')[0])})
```

Result:

```
 {'a': [('b', '4'), ('c', '2')], 'c': [('a', '2'), ('b', '1'), ('d', '8'), ('e', '10')], 'b': [('a', '4'), ('c', '1'), ('d', '5')], 'e': [('c', '10'), ('d', '2'), ('z', '3')], 'd': [('b', '5'), ('c', '8'), ('e', '2'), ('z', '6')], 'z': [('d', '6'), ('e', '3')]}
```